# Перевод настольного wpf приложение в браузерное

Tags: wpf, веб-программирование, браузер, silverlight

Появилось необходимость перевода wpf приложения в браузерное приложения. После поисков решений в сети нашел 2 варианта: Microsoft Silverlight и XBAP, но обе технологии не подошли по некоторым критериям:

1. XBAP не поддерживается в мобильных браузерах;
2. Silverlight не поддерживается в браузерах Opera, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, а также прекращение развития Silverlight.

Вопрос: Как(с помощью чего) реализовать перевод wpf настольное приложение в браузерное?
PS. Необходима поддержка мобильных устройств и основных браузеров.

Comment: Если хотите нормальное Web приложение, то без переписывания логики под Asp .net (core) тут вряд-ли что получится. Предложенные вами варианты - это костыли (причем давно устаревшие), а WPF - это десктоп и только десктоп.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае возможны 2 варианта:

- Переделать приложение под ASP.NET;
- Переписать приложение под другую web платформу.

В первом случае, Вам возможно потребуется меньше работы, т.к. ASP.NET это то же .NET технология и она также поддерживается в тех же C# и VB.NET. Во втором случае приложение однозначно придётся переписывать полностью.

Третьего не дано, т.к.WPF это десктопная платформа.

В своё время предпринимались попытки как-то адаптировать WPF для браузеров, но они насколько мне известно, давно прекращены.